# How do I vectorize multiple columns based on a condition in Pandas?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, vectorization

I am able to successfully vectorize one column, for example:

`df.loc[df['Pos'] == "26,001+", 'column_D'] =  "N/A"`

I want to know how I can do this for multiple columns; I tried something like this, which was unsuccessful:

`df.loc[df['Pos'] == "Between 10,001 and 26,000", 'A' & 'B' & 'C' & 'D' & 'E'] =  "N/A"`

I am expecting for all the listed columns to be transformed using vectorization, if possible.

Comment: Try this `df.loc[df['Pos']=="Between 10,001 and 26,000", ['A','B','C','D','E']] = "N/A"`

Comment: @harryhaller Thank you for the quick reply. I tried what you suggested and it worked!!! Thank you for your help! 

At first I thought it did not work, but that was because I had a case-sensitivity discrepancy in the string I was searching for. Thanks again!

Comment: @harryhaller consider posting an answer containing your solution

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there. Following the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html), the syntax is

```
df.loc[df['Pos']=="Between 10,001 and 26,000", ['A','B','C','D','E']] = "N/A"
```